# Are people used to seeing a "My Cart" link in the header?

Tags: website-design, usability, user-behavior, shopping-cart, header

I have been designing an E-commerce platform where users will be able to buy Apps from the marketplace.

I had thought of placing "My Cart" links in a number of places, such as:

1. Docked widget in the site which follows the user throughout the website.
2. In one of the sidebars. Left/Right
3. In the header as a pull down widget.

And I decided on placing it in the header.

**But are people used to seeing "My Cart" options in the header?**

---

[image: This should be the flow]

Comment: Nice job on the designs.  They are clear and look good.

Comment: Simple and effective design.Easy to understand.

Answer (score 5):

In an E-commerce site I think it has become so synonymous for users to look in the header for their shopping cart. In this case I would say there there is no need to reinvent the wheel, it works and if you were to place the cart in any other location you may confuse a lot of your users. I believe the way you have it designed in your wireframes is a great and usable experience for anyone. Here is an article written in Smashing Magazine about shopping carts that will give you a little more insight into the shopping experience, http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/02/07/shopping-carts-gallery-examples-and-good-practices/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, people are used to seeing a basket or a trolley symbol in the top right of their screens on e-commerce applications.  It doesn't matter whether you use a trolley or a basket, as both are clearly understood.

[image]

I've had some experience with sites that have tried to be original and place the trolley / basket somewhere else, and every time it was confusing and frustrating.  Stick to what we know works unless you have a fantastic reason not to.